# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am filing my javascripts to external files. with this process I came across the following error in Chrome:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL Line:2

```
$(document).bgStretcher({
#if($CURRENTPAGE.pageId==23)

    images: ['/media/backgrounds/homepage/homepage.jpg'], imageWidth: 1860, imageHeight: 1000
    #else
        images: ['/media/backgrounds/Dreamjob_coachfoto_'+pad(randomnumber,3)+'.jpg'], imageWidth: 1860, imageHeight: 1000
    #end
    });
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That `#` is not valid in JavaScript. Comments start with `//` or are enclosed within `/* */` pairs. (Actually I don't know what that stuff is supposed to be, but it's not JavaScript.)

Comment: What language was this in before you moved the code into the external files? It looks like the javascript was preprocessed by a server-side language.

Comment: The `#` lines aren't preprocessor directives, are they? What server-side language are you using?

Comment: Regardless of which server-side language, it looks like you had some javascript in a dynamic file, and you tried to move it directly to a .js file. That won't work, since .js files aren't processed by the server as a dynamic file.

Answer (score 0):

proper syntax ( the syntax on images looks odd, but I couldnt find the full docs for bgstretcher sorry)

```
$(document).bgStretcher({
if($CURRENTPAGE.pageId==23) {

images: ['/media/backgrounds/homepage/homepage.jpg'], imageWidth: 1860, imageHeight: 1000
}  
 else   {
    images: ['/media/backgrounds/Dreamjob_coachfoto_'+pad(randomnumber,3)+'.jpg'],              imageWidth: 1860, imageHeight: 1000
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug with Firefox (using Firebug), it will give you more info than Chrome on this type of error.